# Create Directory that ends with / in Android

Tags: java, android, file

i need to create a directory that ends with / , but when i do this it automatically deletes the / , is it possible?

```
String folderPath =Item.getPath()+"_Docs/");

File folder=new File(folderPath);
```

When i do folder.getPath i onyl get /_Docs

I'd really appreciate the help , thank you

Comment: why you need to create it with a slash at the end? normally the OS will do it for you once you add the first file to the directory

Comment: Name of file can not contains these characters `* / \" : ? | < >`. So please forget it

Answer (score 3):

> is it possible?

No. Similarly, you cannot create a directory that ends in `/` on macOS or Linux, and you cannot create a directory that ends in `\` on Windows.